# How do I query a varchar and #1054 Unknown column 'variable' in 'where clause'

Tags: varchar

In MySQL, how do I query a varchar?  I can query numbers not characters.

```
public function getRfis()
{
  $projnum = $this->_item->proj_num;


  $db    = JFactory::getDbo();

  $query = $db->getQuery(true);

  $query->select('*');
  $query->from('#__projxrfi_request');

  $query->where('project_num =' .$projnum) ;


  $db->setQuery($query);

  $this->rfis = $db->loadObjectlist();

  return ($this->rfis);

 }
```

The $projnum is what Im looking for.

Also, if it doesn't find a match...no records exist...I get an error message,

## 1054 Unknown column 'variable' in 'where clause'

How do I prevent this and return null or 0.

Thank you